# How can I configure Jenkins Gerrit Trigger event to exclude a file path?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

## Background

My git repository is hosted by a Gerrit server.   We also use Jenkins, along with the Gerrit Event and Git Plugin, to trigger automatic jenkins jobs build when a review is pushed to Gerrit.

Say the git repo has the following folder structure

```
ProjectA
    - .git
    - folderA
    - folderA/folderA1
    - folderA/manual_tests
    - folderA/manual_tests/file1
    - folderB
    - folderB/folderB1
    - folderB/manual_tests/file2
    - folderC
    - folderC/folderC1
    - folderC/manual_tests/file3
    - folderD
    - folderD/folderD1
    - folderD/folderD1/FolderD11
    - folderD/folderD1/FolderD11/manual_tests/file4
    - folderD/folderD1/FolderD12
    - folderD/folderD2
```

Currently, the Jenkins job is defined to run on all branches by specifying Type `Path` with pattern  `**`.  This config causes the job to run with every review.

## The Issue

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- If the code review only contains changes made to any `manual_tests` folder, I don't want to Jenkins Jobs to get triggered.
- If the review contains at least least one file/folder that is not `manual_tests`, the trigger the jobs

I tried adding a `File Path` with type `RegExp` with a pattern of `(?!.*manual_tests.*).*`, but this did not achieve my end goals.  I tried various regular expression patterns, but I never got the end goal.

Is it possible to not trigger a Jenkins job if a gerrit review only contains changes in `manual_tests` folders?

Comment: have you tried this format explained here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5334825/1342413

Answer (score 2):

The trick to getting this working is that the COMMIT_MSG file must be omitted in the regex as well.

This bug report describes the problem and workaround: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19891

The fix is simply to use the following RegExp pattern:

```
^((?!manual_tests|\/COMMIT_MSG).)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Add Topic` button below the form reveals such a functionality.

[image: screen shot from Gerrit]

The help text explains:

> Then you can optionally provide the name of the specific file path(s) and topic names to trigger on.
>
> - To only trigger builds if the patch set contains files in a certain folder.
> - To only trigger builds if the change belongs to a topic.

Comment: That is only an include, but sometimes you need to exclude something from an included path.